# Test the subtraction of multiple unsigned int

Tags: c

After a few unsuccessful searches, I still don't know if there's a way to substract two `unsigned int` (or more) and detect if the result of this substraction is negative (or not).

I've try things like :

```
if(((int)x - (int)y) < 0)
```

But I don't think it's the best way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realize that what you intend by

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;

if (x - y < 0)
```

is mathematically equivalent to:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;

if (y > x)
```

**EDIT**

There aren't many questions for which I can assert a definitive proof, but I can for this one.  It's basic inequality algebra:

```
x - y < 0
```

add y to both sides:

```
x < y, which is the same as y > x.
```

You can do similarly with more variables, if you need:

```
x - y - z < 0 == x < y + z, or y + z > x
```

see [chux's comment to his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132489/1404311), though, for a valid warning about integer overflow when dealing with multiple values.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but this works only with two values and no more is that it ?

Comment: Rather than deal with casting the values and subtracting and comparing the result to 0, just check if one is greater than the other.  Your `if` statement will evaluate the same in any case.  I'm not sure what you mean by "only two values".  You can just as easily say `if (x - y - z < 0)` is equivalent to `y + z > x`, if you need to.  (I'm just doing basic [inequality arithmetic](http://www.math.com/school/subject2/lessons/S2U3L4GL.html).)

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein `y + z > x` has trouble is `y + z` overflows.

Comment: @chux Yes, I just saw your comment on your post, and was mentioning it.  (I have to look up how to link to it...)

Answer (score 4):

Simply compare.

```
unsigned x, y, diff;
diff = x - y;
if (x < y) {
  printf("Difference is negative and not representable as an unsigned.\n");
}
```

---

[Edit]  OP change from "2 unsigned int" to "multiple unsigned int"

Confident doing N*(N-1)/2 compares would be needed if a wider integer width is not available for subtracting N `unsigned`.

With N > 2, simplest, if available, to use wider integers.  Such as

```
long long diff;
// or
#include <stdint.h>
intmax_t diff;
```

Depending though on your platform, these type may or may not be wider than `unsigned.`  Certainly not narrower.

Note: this issue similarly applies to multiple `signed int` too.  Other compares are use though.  But that is another question.

Comment: @Aperçu if dealing with more than 2 `unsigned` variables, consider using wider `int` types.  `a + b > c` fails if `a + b` overflows, even though mathematical result `a + b - c` may fit in an `unsigned`.

Comment: @Aperçu  I think one would end up doing N*(N-1)/2 compares if one is restricted to no-wider integers.  With `N > 2`, simplest, if available, to use wider integers.